# How to set QTreeWidget all row editable?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

I'm making a soft with Python and PYQT5 and my question is how to set editable all row in a `QTreeWidget`?

Here is my code to create a row in *`self.filaireTab`* (which is a `QTreeWidget`) when a button is clicked:

```
def plusFunction(self):
        """ Return nothing
        Add CTA parent in tab.
        """
        try:
            root = self.filaireTab.invisibleRootItem()
            child_count = root.childCount()
            string = "CTA"+str(child_count+1)
            l = QTreeWidgetItem([string])
            self.filaireTab.addTopLevelItem(l)
        except:
            pass
```

I know there is a flag to set, it is possible in QtCreator but in the code i only find C++ example which didn't help me at all. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`setFlags()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#setFlags) with `Qt.ItemIsEditable` along with the default ones (otherwise you'll end up with a disabled item).

```
l = QTreeWidgetItem([string])
l.setFlags(l.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```